# Replace all text in a rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, replace, richtextbox

I have a problem while trying to replace all text matching a particular word in a `rich text box`. This is the code i use

```
    public static void ReplaceAll(RichTextBox myRtb, string word, string replacer)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < myRtb.Text.LastIndexOf(word))
        {
            int location = myRtb.Find(word, index, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            myRtb.Select(location, word.Length);
            myRtb.SelectedText = replacer;
            index++;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
    }

    private void btnReplaceAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 text = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        ReplaceAll(text.Current, txtFind2.Text, txtReplace.Text);
    }
```

This works well but i have noticed a little malfunction when i try to replace a letter with itself and another letter.

For example i want to replace all the `e` in `Welcome to Nigeria` with `ea`.

This is what i get `Weaalcomeaaaaaaa to Nigeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaria`.

And the message box shows `23` when there are only three `e`. Pls what am i doing wrong and how can i correct it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
yourRichTextBox.Text = yourRichTextBox.Text.Replace("e","ea");
```

If you want to report the number of matches (which are replaced), you can try using `Regex` like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Matches(yourRichTextBox.Text, "e").Count.ToString());
```

### UPDATE

Of course, using the method above has **expensive cost in memory**, you can use some loop in combination with `Regex` to achieve some kind of advanced replacing engine like this:

```
public void ReplaceAll(RichTextBox myRtb, string word, string replacement){
   int i = 0;
   int n = 0;
   int a = replacement.Length - word.Length;
   foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(myRtb.Text, word)){          
      myRtb.Select(m.Index + i, word.Length);
      i += a;
      myRtb.SelectedText = replacement;
      n++;
   }
   MessageBox.Show("Replaced " + n + " matches!");
}
```

Comment: Depending on how robust your looking to make this you can add functionality for replacing patterns and expressions by utilizing Regex replacement as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.aspx

Comment: @Slump we will use `Regex` for complex patterns, we don't need such a powerful tool with simple patterns like in this case.

Comment: Doesn't work. I put in the loop but it doesn't perform any action

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi **You don't need any loop**, just that line of code.

Comment: @KingKing Agreed. Just a suggestion if PreciousTijesunimi should desire adding the functionality in the future.

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi if you want to use while loop (which may be better in term of saving memory) you may want to look at my update.