# How to search and replace words in a WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I've found several examples that do this but with richTextBox instead. Is it even possible to replace words in a multi-line TextBox?

Comment: You should be able to go through each string in the string array and use the replace function on each string in the array (this will miss if the word is broken up on 2 lines)

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Did you write some lines of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all text in a rich text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905193/replace-all-text-in-a-rich-text-box)

Comment: @orgtigger You are right, I was having a brain fart I guess. The problem I was having was with the way I was splitting the text I was then trying to replace so the replace wasn't finding what I needed it to.

Comment: <TextBox
  Name="txtmultiline"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  AcceptsReturn="True"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
>
  This TextBox will allow the user to enter multiple lines of text.  When the RETURN key is pressed, 
</TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for searchin' the next word automatically in textbox

```
int t = 0;
 private void FindNext(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = t; i < NoteText.Text.Length-SearchBar.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            string x = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < SearchBar.Text.Length; j++)
            {
                if(SearchBar.Text[j] == NoteText.Text[i+j])
                {
                    x += NoteText.Text[i + j] + "";
                }
                else
                {
                    x = "";
                }
            }
            if(x == SearchBar.Text)
            {
                t = i+1;
                NoteText.Focus();
                NoteText.SelectAll();
                NoteText.Select(i, SearchBar.Text.Length);
                break;
            }
            if(i==NoteText.Text.Length - SearchBar.Text.Length - 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The search was completed");
                t = 0;
            }
            s = t;
        }
    }
```